# ¿Por qué la función filter ignora NaN?

Tags: javascript

Haciendo una función simple que toma un array, y que devuelve el mismo array con los elementos false, null, 0, "", undefined, y NaN eliminados del array.

Aquí dejo varias "situaciones" dónde no funciona (excepto la primera si funciona) y debajo el resultado que da cada una.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {

 var filtered = arr.filter(function(value, index, arr){

    return value != null ;

 })
return filtered
}

bouncer([7, null, 9]);

//ELIMINA null correctamente

function bouncer(arr) {

 var filtered = arr.filter(function(value, index, arr){

    return value != null | "" ;

 })
return filtered
}

bouncer([7, null, "", 9]);

// ELIMINA "" pero no null!

function bouncer(arr) {

 var filtered = arr.filter(function(value, index, arr){

    return value != NaN ;

 })
return filtered
}

bouncer([7, NaN, 9]);

////No ELIMINA Nada!

function bouncer(arr) {

  var filtered = arr.filter(function(value, index, arr){

    return value != false ;

 })
return filtered
}

bouncer([7, null, "", 9]);

//ELIMINA "" pero no null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando haces una comparación con `==` o `!=`, Javascript intenta primero convertir los valores a un tipo común. Puedes leer [este artículo de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) para entender el asunto.

Ahora, los valores que tú quieres filtrar son justamente los valores que JavaScript considera ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy). ¿Qué quiere decir falsy exactamente? Pues que al convertiros a tipo `boolean`, se transformarán en `false`.

Algo tan simple como esto funcionaría:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  var filtered = arr.filter(function(value, index, arr) {
    return value;
  })
  return filtered
}

var filtrados = bouncer([7, null, undefined, false, 0, '', NaN, 9])
console.log(filtrados);
```

porque estamos forzando la conversión de `value`a tipo `boolean`.

Edit: existe una manera más corta para conseguir el mismo resultado:

```js
var array = [7, null, undefined, false, 0, '', NaN, 9];
var filtrados = array.filter(Boolean);
console.log(filtrados);
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes unos cuantos fallos:

```
return value != null | "" ;
```

Las comparaciones no funcionan así ... y estás usando el **operador binario**. Debería ser

```
return ( value !== null ) && ( value !== "" );
```

Otro, y este te va a gustar:

```
return value != NaN;
```

`Nan` es distinto a todo ... ¡ incluso a si mismo !

```
return value === value;
```

El último:

```
return value != false;
```

Ya lo sabes: se realiza una promoción de tipos. Debería ser:

```
return value;
```