# Filtrar elementos booleanos dentro de un Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones

he pasado un par de horas atascado con este ejercicio de FreeCodeCamp:

Falsy Bouncer
Remove all falsy values from an array.

Falsy values in JavaScript are false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN.

Hint: Try converting each value to a Boolean.

---

Ya he conseguido la solucion al ejercicio de mano de @David Silva la cual puedes visitar directamente aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/248236/115649

Pero se mantiene la duda de por qué mi código no está funcionando:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let aux = [];
  let x;

  function state(x) {
    if (x == false ||
      x == null ||
      x == 0 ||
      x == "" ||
      x == undefined ||
      x == NaN ||
    ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    x = arr[i];
    if (state(x) === true) {
      aux.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return aux;
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Esto me filtra correctamente todos los valores pasados por mi funcion state() menos el NaN.

El NaN siempre termina colandose dentro del aux pese a que lo he pasado como string o booleano.

Agradecería que pudieran aclararme este punto.

Gracias capos :)

Comment: Por definición del lenguaje `NaN == NaN` es `false`.  https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, no sospeché fuese este el motivo.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @Lobos en los comentarios, el problema principal en el código es que `NaN == NaN` es `false`, dicho esto, en lugar de comparar cada valor con el falsy se puede castear cada valor como booleano usando `!!` y asi filtrarlos.

```js
const arr = [7, "ate", "", false, 9, 0, NaN, null, undefined];

const res = arr.filter(e=>!!e);

console.log(res);
```

El primer `!` castea el valor como booleano y retorna el contrario (porque estamos negando), el segundo niega la negación.